# Windows 8 Pro Hyper-V Manager network connection

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04, hyper-v

Need to create a VM instance of Ubuntu 12 hosted on Windows 8 Pro. Discovered Hyper-V. Got it installed like a charm with OS booting up real nice.

However, for the life of me and at least two hours of my life, I have been unable to configure Virtual Switches, Network Adapters, etc to reach the net.

I've asked Mr Google and have not found clear directions... well none that I worked for me.

I am not entirely with experience in this area. I have used VirtualBox with good success. Just figured Hyper-V would be better on top of my dream-machine Windows 8 Pro box.

If you have it working, please do share.

Thank you!!

Comment: In the Hyper V Manager, did you create an `External` Virtual Network? Did you add your Ubuntu VM's network card to that network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 works in Hyper-V without modification.  For older Linux distros, you might need to add a driver to Linux to see the virtual NIC.

In the Hyper-V world, you first create a virtual switch, and then you install a guest OS.  It sounds like you have the hang of the overall concept, so you're probably very close to getting it working.  Perhaps when you created the virtual NIC, you bound it to your PC's wired Ethernet NIC instead of your WiFi NIC?  That assumes you use WiFi and not wired Ethernet.  In other words, your virtual NIC might be bound to a real NIC which isn't in use.

I could walk you through it using Hyper-V manager, but Mathew John from the Hyper-V team already tells you everything you need to know in a video halfway down a blog post called [Bringing Hyper-V to Windows 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/bringing-hyper-v-to-windows-8).  It's only 2 minutes long, and worth a watch.

Comment: Watching the video was just what I needed. The key issue I had was that I had not created a Virtual Switch BEFORE installing the OS. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. :)